# An image on top of a css box does not show

Tags: css

I have two horizontal lines on top of each other and I want to put a image on top of those lines, but I am not able to achieve this with CSS. The image gets hidden behind the horizontal lines.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xdedrnzs/)

here is the image 
[image: the image I am trying to get]

my HTML

```
<div class="creambar"></div> 
<div class="graybar silhouette"></div>
```

my CSS

```
graybar { height: 20px;  background-color: #343434; width: 100%; }
.graybar .silhouette { background: url("graphics/panr_silhouette_2.png"); }
.creambar { height: 5px; background-color: #d4c293; width: 100%; }
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle...(http://jsfiddle.net) ???

Comment: Also, in your CSS code, change `graybar` to `.graybar` and `.graybar .silhouette` to `.graybar.silhouette`

Answer (score 2):

Is something like this that you want?

```css
.creambar {
  border-bottom: 20px solid #343434;
  border-top: 4px solid #d4c293;
  bottom: -69px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.graybar {
  border-bottom: 20px solid #343434;
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xbAl.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
  height: 62px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="creambar"></div>
<div class="graybar"></div>
```

See Full Page.

Comment: it creates a gap between the two bars, and if I take the height:62px; the image goes away

Comment: what gap? I don't see any gap! which image goes away?

Comment: it looks like this 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fv7lacgp8dvmw7j/Screen%20Shot%202015-07-14%20at%204.09.01%20PM.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Change the z-index. The z-index of the image you want to show should have the highest value.

.graybar .silhouette z-index should be higher than the z-index of .graybar.

```
.graybar { height: 20px;  background-color: #343434; width: 100%; z-index:1;}
.graybar.silhouette { background: url("graphics/panr_silhouette_2.png"); z-index:3; }
.creambar { height: 5px; background-color: #d4c293; width: 100%; z-index:1; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I simply changed the `z-index` For one to be on top of the other. You can read more on the `z-index` property [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

```
<div class="creambar"></div> 
<div class="graybar silhouette"></div>
```

CSS

```
graybar { height: 20px;  background-color: #343434; width: 100%;position:relative;z-index:1; }
.graybar .silhouette { background: url("graphics/panr_silhouette_2.png"); position:relative;z-index:99; }
.creambar { height: 5px; background-color: #d4c293; width: 100%; position:relative;z-index:1; }
```